# Getting the sum of an array of doubles in swift

Tags: arrays, core-data, swift, double, reduce

I have an array of string numbers that I am fetching from core data and converting to doubles. I would like to get their sum once I've done this, but I get an error.  I've tried it like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        //CoreData
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
        let managedContext : NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
        var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Log")
        fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;
        var results: NSArray = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil)!

        if (results.count > 0) {
            for res in results {
                var totalWorkTimeInHoursString = res.valueForKey("totalWorkTimeInHoursString")  as String
                //get double value of strings array
                var totalWorkTimeInHoursNSString = NSString(string: totalWorkTimeInHoursString)
                var totalWorkTimeInHoursNSStringDoubleValue = totalWorkTimeInHoursNSString.doubleValue
                lastLogHoursWorked.text = "\(totalWorkTimeInHoursString) hours"
                totalHoursWorkedSum.text = "\(totalWorkTimeInHoursNSStringDoubleValue)"

                let sum = totalWorkTimeInHoursNSStringDoubleValue.reduce(0,+)
                    //throws an error saying 'Double' does not have a member named 'reduce'

                println(totalWorkTimeInHoursNSStringDoubleValue)
                    //lists the array of doubles in console successfully
                println(sum)
                    //checking to see if 'sum' works properly

        }
        }else {
            println("zero results returned, potential error")
        }
}
```

Am I approaching this properly? what am I missing?

Comment: According to the docs (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/Array.html) `reduce` is applied to a *collection* -- not a double.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at your code, I deduce that `results` is an array of dictionaries, and each dictionary has a `totalWorkTimeInHoursString` key, whose value is a string representation of a double number.

I would solve it using a bit of functional approach, using `filter`, `map` and `reduce`:

```
if results.count > 0 {
    var res = results as [NSDictionary]

    var result = res.filter { $0["totalWorkTimeInHoursString"] is String }
        .map { ($0["totalWorkTimeInHoursString"] as NSString).doubleValue }
        .reduce (0, +)
}
```

What the code does:

- convert the `results` array into an array of `NSDictionary`
- filter the array by removing all elements (which are dictionaries) not having the `totalWorkTimeInHoursString` key, or whose corresponding value is not a string
- convert each element of the array to a double, by extracting the value corresponding to the `totalWorkTimeInHoursString` key, converting to `NSString` and then to `Double`
- apply the `reduce` method, passing the `+` operator to sum up the resulting array of `Double`

This is the data I tested my solution with, in a playground:

```
var results: NSArray = [
    ["totalWorkTimeInHoursString": "10.0"],
    ["totalWorkTimeInHoursString": "5.0"]
]
```

Comment: Just tried that, it's throwing an error "fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type"

Comment: Is it possible that some of the elements in `results` is not a dictionary? If not, do you have any additional detail about that error?

Comment: at this point what I'm trying to do is retrieve a list of core data attributes (which are numbers stored as strings) and get the sum of them all. I currently have them all loading into a tableview appropriately, but in this view controller I simply want a label with their sum. Hopefully this explains my situation a bit better? Thanks for your patience! :)

Comment: That explains what your goal is, but unfortunately doesn't help fixing the error :). I think the problem is about `executeFetchRequest` returnin an array of `NSManagedObject` (I don't use coredata too much, so not sure). You can try casting `result` to `[NSManagedObject]` instead of `[NSDictionary]`, and solve the compilation issues (use `valueForKey` instead of the subscript)

Answer (score 3):

`Reduce` is a function on an `Array`. When you say `array.reduce(0, +)`, what you are saying is, "here's an array of doubles. Combine the elements into a single value by applying the `+` operation on the elements, starting with 0 as the value".

You cannot `reduce` a single value.

Comment: but "totalWorkTimeInHoursNSStringDoubleValue" is an array of doubles in this case correct? At least it prints an array of doubles to the console when I call it. Is there any other way of doing it to achieve my goal?

Comment: No, it's not an array, it's a Double. If you're seeing an array of doubles, please cut/paste what you're seeing.

Comment: @Leighton Yes, you've converted a string to a double value. It's a double.