# How to sum a double attribute from CoreData in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, core-data, swift, double

I asked a similar question here: [Getting the sum of an array of doubles in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27322031/getting-the-sum-of-an-array-of-doubles-in-swift/27323918?noredirect=1#comment43108361_27323918)

but I still haven't gotten to a solution. Since the last question I changed my core data attribute type to double. The question is this. How to I get a sum of all those doubles stored in core data?

Right now I have:

```
// Get CoreData
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
let managedContext : NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Log")
fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;
var results: NSArray = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil)!

//attempt to type cast a logs array
var logs = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil)!
var logsArray = logs as NSArray as [Double]
var totalHoursWorkedSum = logsArray.reduce(0, combine: +)
//this builds, but crashes the app with 'EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION' when I try to set a label.text with 'totalHoursWorkedSum'
```

I'm really not sure what else to try so I'm open to any different approaches that may accomplish the same goal.

Here's how I get and store the original values:

```
//Time logging
var punchInTime : NSDate = punchTimes.objectForKey("punchInTime") as NSDate
var punchOutTime = NSDate()
var totalWorkTime  = NSDate().timeIntervalSinceDate(punchInTime)
//"punchInTime" is stored in NSUserDefaults
var totalWorkTimeInHoursNotRounded = (totalWorkTime/60/60)

var totalWorkTimeInHours = Double(round(1000*totalWorkTimeInHoursNotRounded)/1000)
//the rounded form of the above


//format a date
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .FullStyle

//Save to CoreData
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
let managedContext : NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Log", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

var newLog = DataModel(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
newLog.totalWorkTimeInHours = totalWorkTimeInHours
newLog.dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())

managedContext.save(nil)

punchTimes.objectForKey("punchInTime") == nil
```

Comment: `logsArray` is an array of dictionaries. The doubles are within its entries.

Comment: To clarify, `logsArray` is an array of dictionaries NOT an array of doubles as you have in your code. That's the problem. You can't `reduce` an array of dictionaries.

Comment: ok, so how would I make an array of doubles out of those dictionaries? or is that even the best way of approaching it?

Comment: How's your core data structured? Are there various keys linked to doubles? And if so, what are those keys?

Comment: yes, I have two entities "totalWorkTimeInHours" which is an NSTimeInterval (aka Double) that is rounded down two three decimal places and then stored under its key. The other one is "dateString" which simply adds a date label to the detailTextLabel in my table view. I'll add the code where I store these in Core Data.

Comment: So you want to pull the "totalWorkTimeInHours" values out of the core data array then add them together? Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Lyndsey Scott Yes exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current code, you're attempting to cast `logsArray` as an array of doubles when it's in fact an array of `NSManagedObject`s. That's why you're getting an error when you attempt to `reduce` the array.

To get the sum of the double values associated with your "totalWorkTimeInHours" key in Core Data, you have to access the "totalWorkTimeInHours" key from each `NSManagedObject` returned from your fetch request then add them together, ex:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //CoreData
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    let managedContext : NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!
    var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Log")
    fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false;
    var results: NSArray = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil)!

    var totalHoursWorkedSum: Double = 0
    for res in results {
        var totalWorkTimeInHours = res.valueForKey("totalWorkTimeInHours") as Double
        totalHoursWorkedSum += totalWorkTimeInHours
    }

    print("Sum = \(totalHoursWorkedSum)")
}
```

Comment: Perfect! You're a lifesaver. Thanks much! I wouldn't have thought it would be that simple. lol

Comment: *"... when it's in fact an array of dictionaries ..."* – no, it is an array of NSManagedObject, unless you have explicitly set `fetchRequest.resultType = .DictionaryResultType`.

Comment: @MartinR The terminology may be off (and I may edit once I get a chance to confirm), but the NSManagedObject can be accessed by key just like a dictionary and this code should work.

Comment: Yes, my remark was only about the terminology. `valueForKey()` works for managed objects as well.

Answer (score 15):

You *can* use `reduce` to add the double values of the fetched managed objects.
In the "combining closure" you have to get the double value of the `totalWorkTimeInHours`
attribute:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Log")

var error : NSError?
let results = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error)
if let logs = results as? [Log] {
    let totalHoursWorkedSum = reduce(logs, 0.0) { $0 + $1.totalWorkTimeInHours.doubleValue }
    println(totalHoursWorkedSum)
} else {
    println("fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Alternatively you can use "Key-Value Coding" to sum the double values in the
array of fetched objects. This is quite similar to Lyndseys's answer, only without
an *explicit* loop:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Log")
var error : NSError?

if let results  = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) {
    let logs = results as NSArray
    let sum = logs.valueForKeyPath("@sum.totalWorkTimeInHours") as NSNumber
    let totalHoursWorkedSum = sum.doubleValue
    println(totalHoursWorkedSum)
} else {
    println("fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
}
```

**But there is a better way:** You create an 
"expression description" for the sum of all totalWorkTimeInHours values:

```
let expressionDesc = NSExpressionDescription()
expressionDesc.name = "sumOftotalWorkTimeInHours"
expressionDesc.expression = NSExpression(forFunction: "sum:",
         arguments:[NSExpression(forKeyPath: "totalWorkTimeInHours")])
expressionDesc.expressionResultType = .DoubleAttributeType
```

and then a fetch request which fetches only this sum:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Log")
fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = [expressionDesc]
fetchRequest.resultType = .DictionaryResultType

var error : NSError?
if let results  = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) {
    let dict = results[0] as [String:Double]
    let totalHoursWorkedSum = dict["sumOftotalWorkTimeInHours"]!
    println(totalHoursWorkedSum)
} else {
    println("fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
}
```

The advantage is that the sum is calculated on the SQLite level, you don't have to
fetch all the objects into memory.

A possible disadvantage is that this request only fetches the values that are stored
in the persistent store, and ignores any unsaved changes in the mangaged object context.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks.

Comment: Your above code @Martin is working great but can we add a predicate for this Fetch Request