# How to sum values in attributes Core Data Swift 5

Tags: xcode, core-data, swift5

Im junior and not found anywhere how to sum values in attributes Core Data. Through which method can this be done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sum a double attribute from CoreData in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27344756/how-to-sum-a-double-attribute-from-coredata-in-swift)

Comment: Can you describe what you need in more detail? What attributes, what kind of summing, in what situation, etc?

Comment: I have 3 attributes. For example title, price and totalPrice. And want sum all data (Double) from price attributes and write to totalPrice. Can you help me? I don’t know of why method I can do it. I have many example of Swift 3 but they don’t work now.

Comment: Maybe you advice where I can read of this.